# Encrypt file and service request in Cordova WKWebView

Tags: ios, cordova, wkwebview

`uiwebview` is used in the mobile bank application with `cordova` and `phonegap`, but Apple has made it obsolete and I want to use `wkwebview`.

For this, I changed platform to iOS 6 and because of `urlprptocol.h` not found error.

I removed the crypt-file plugin, but now it doesn't load two of my files that are requested to the service and are encrypted

And when I remove the encrypt, my requests do not go to the service.